# how to 'push --tags' ignoring some?

Tags: git

I'd like to push all tags except a couple which are not needed. Is it possible do it without deleting them first?

The scenario: an automated release system assigns a release tag to the latest commit of the master branch, say V3.1. It also *moves* the 'LATEST' tag to the same new commit.  (in reality there are more unique and non-unique tags created).

So, i'd like to do `push --tags` but ignore the 'LATEST'. Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly, I see two ways to do what you need :

1. push only the tag your job just created, e.g : store the tag name in some `$tag` variable, and run :

   ```
   git push origin $tag
   ```
2. you want to push more than one tag, and tags created by the job will all follow the same pattern : `V3.1`, `V3.2` etc ...
   in that case, use a refspec which matches only those tags :

   ```
   git push origin "refs/tags/V*:refs/tags/V*"
   ```

See the refspec section of `git help push`

Comment: testing on my machine : if I just push the tag's name, no automagic tag push is added ;  I couldn't say what settings could change the behavior of `git push` though

Answer (score 2):

Git tags aren't designed to be moved, and the manual describes this.

> Git supports two types of tags: lightweight and annotated.
>
> A lightweight tag is very much like a branch that doesn’t change — it’s just a pointer to a specific commit.
>
> Annotated tags, however, are stored as full objects in the Git database. They’re checksummed; contain the tagger name, email, and date; have a tagging message; and can be signed and verified with GNU Privacy Guard (GPG). (Source: [Git Manual](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging))

You probably want to use a branch to point to the latest commit rather than a tag. As alluded to in the excerpt quoted above, a lightweight tag is just the same as a branch except it doesn't change, and an annotated tag is a lightweight tag with some additional information attached to it. This is useful if you want to sign the tag so you can audit who created a given release, but holds no benefit if you're using a tag to point to a moving target. That's what branches are for.

To change where a branch points, checkout the branch and reset --hard to the new sha. For example (assuming `de39a48` is the new latest commit after the release).

`git checkout latest
git reset --hard de39a48`

Comment: For the last part, you can also do `git branch -f latest de39a48` in one step, even from another branch.

Comment: these are light-weight tags. The releaser deletes 'latests' and recreates it then. So, efficiently it gets moved. And, the releases are done on the master branch. No branching happens in this case.

Comment: @Serge if it's a lightweight tag that you're moving then use a branch. That's what they're for.

Comment: @Haegin yes, but i do not have any control over the release script. It does what it does.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want `LATEST` treated like a tag, don't make it a tag. You can keep utterly arbitrary thumbs into the commit graph,

```
git update-ref LATEST v3.1^{}
```

is the simplest, though it'd be approporiate to carp at that for its inconsiderate use of a conventionally-reserved namespace (it's a completely global ref, like HEAD), so perhaps `git update-ref refs/cithumbs/LATEST v3.1^{}` would be better professional engineering.  The `^{}` is there to be sure of reaching the underlying commit (see [git help revisions](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions)) in case you're using annotated (e.g. signed or commented) tags that carry the data in their own object.

Since git's branching is quite literally incredibly lightweight—as in, it's difficult to get people used to other vcs's gyrations to credit just how easy this can be—you could just use a branch:

```
git branch -f LATEST v3.1
```

which is essentially exactly equivalent to

```
git update-ref refs/heads/LATEST v3.1^{}
```

(the `branch` command also sets up a reflog by default, which you might want and can get `update-ref to do for you for any ref, see the reflog docs).

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
git push --dry-run --tags LATEST^
```

It will push every tag until the commit *before* the one your tag LATEST points to.

I'm not sure whether `push` command's refspec accepts commit hashes, but it's a dry-run so it won't actually affect anything. Then proceed with the real thing if the output fits your expectations.

Comment: @Serge It sure should. What does the --dry-run output look like?

Comment: but the new tags point to the latest commit as well as the 'LATEST'.

Comment: @Serge Oh. So you mean that both the wanted and unwanted tags may point at the same commits? If so, I'm at a loss for a solution, mine won't work.